Theory for PCB resonator with special kind of mode
I have built a resonator in CST as shown bellow .
I need to make the resonator be in such mode so the H-field will be normal to PCB plane. (W direction in the photo).
Surface shows two peaks.
As you can see I have peak magnetic field at the edges.
Is there some PCB way to excite magnetic field peak in the middle of the ring in the direction of W (normal to PCB plane)?





Consider to spell out acronyms.

(PCB=printed circuit board.) Not likely, the "basic" mode of the resonator, the so-called qTEM (quasi TEM modes), and this is what you seem to be exciting, and its harmonics are such that there is an approximate magnetic  wall parallel with $\hat z $ between a bit off the edge of the strip and the ground plane, so the magnetic and electric fields are very small in the center. That it starts at "a bit off the edge" lets you excite it there.

How about a split ring resonator? You have a continuous ring and as a result you have a hard time getting the current to run around the circumference. If  you split the ring the gap will act as a capacitor and the ring as a coil - it will be fairly close to a standard LC circuit with a circular coil. The field it will produce will be perpendicular to the plane. You can control the frequency by changing the diameter of the ring and width of the gap. To get 14 GHz the thing will have to be quite small though.
The trickier bit will be to couple to it - I guess a trace similar to what you already have there could work but it will likely require some experimentation to get it right.

Hello ,I succseeded and made a breakthrew .
As you can see I removed the ground plane bellow the ring and I got the H-field prepandicular to the plane.
How do you reccomend to increase the coupling to this mode?
Is there some intuitions I could use?
Thanks.
https://ibb.co/zf4fSHL
https://ibb.co/QD4Bnp2
https://ibb.co/SP8ZJmD
https://ibb.co/6stTjkc
https://ibb.co/JdBnhPq
